# How can I find then next grid block in the grid by direction?

Tags: unity, c#

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class GenerateGrid : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject gridPrefab;
    public GameObject pathPrefab;
    public List<Text> texts = new List<Text>();

    private Transform[,] gridBlocks;

    private List<Vector3> gridBlocksPositions = new List<Vector3>();
    private List<Vector3> gridOuterBlocks = new List<Vector3>();

    private Transform startBlockPOs;
    private Transform endBlockPos;

    public int gridWidth = 10;
    public int gridHeight = 10;
    public int gap;
    public float spawnSpeed = 0;
    public bool gridGenerated = false;

    Transform next;

    void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(CreateGrid());
    }

    IEnumerator CreateGrid()
    {
        gridBlocks = new Transform[gridWidth, gridHeight];

        for (int x = 0; x < gridWidth; x++)
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(spawnSpeed);

            for (int z = 0; z < gridHeight; z++)
            {
                yield return new WaitForSeconds(spawnSpeed);

                GameObject block = Instantiate(gridPrefab, Vector3.zero, gridPrefab.transform.rotation) as GameObject;
                block.transform.parent = transform;
                block.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(x + x * gap, 0, z + z * gap);
                block.tag = "Grid Block";
                texts.Add(block.GetComponentInChildren<Text>());
                gridBlocks[x, z] = block.transform;
                gridBlocksPositions.Add(block.transform.position);
                if ((x == 0) || (x == gridWidth - 1) || (z == 0) || (z == gridHeight - 1))
                {
                    gridOuterBlocks.Add(block.transform.position);

                    var cubeRenderer = block.GetComponent<Renderer>();
                    cubeRenderer.material.SetColor("_Color", Color.red);
                }
            }
        }

        if (Random.Range(0, 2) == 0)
        {
            var blockRenderer = gridBlocks[0, Random.Range(0, gridHeight)].GetComponent<Renderer>();
            blockRenderer.material.SetColor("_Color", Color.blue);
            startBlockPOs = blockRenderer.transform;
            blockRenderer = gridBlocks[gridWidth - 1, Random.Range(0, gridHeight)].GetComponent<Renderer>();
            blockRenderer.material.SetColor("_Color", Color.blue);
            endBlockPos = blockRenderer.transform;
        }
        else
        {
            var blockRenderer = gridBlocks[Random.Range(0, gridWidth), 0].GetComponent<Renderer>();
            blockRenderer.material.SetColor("_Color", Color.blue);
            startBlockPOs = blockRenderer.transform;
            blockRenderer = gridBlocks[Random.Range(0, gridWidth), gridHeight - 1].GetComponent<Renderer>();
            blockRenderer.material.SetColor("_Color", Color.blue);
            endBlockPos = blockRenderer.transform;
        }
        gridGenerated = true;

        var next = gridBlocks[Random.Range(0, gridWidth), gridHeight - 1];
    }
}
```

The main goal is to create each time a random path between start position and end position not the shortest path just a random path without return on the same moved blocks and without the 4 corners and without the red's. The red's are only for the start and end positions.

The variable next at the bottom is type transform but I want to get the index of the gridBlocks for example 1,2 or 9,7 depending on the startBlockPOs and then to move to the next block to color in blue the next possible block.

First the 4 corners should not be start or end positions at all.
Second the grid is a square and I don't want to move in diagonal.
It can move only forward , left , right directions.
And should be random to select the next possible direction.

How do I move out the 4 corners from the possible start/end positions ?

And how can I find the next possible directions to move for example the first move can be only forward I don't want to move on the red's so the start position next possible block to move to is the one in front of him.

And how do I move by code I mean ho do I color in the blue the next one ? The variable next is a transform but how do I get the next one from the start position block ?

[image: Grid]